# Why wont this php if statement work?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, assign

I have a variable called `$type`that is either `type1` or `type2`. I have another variable called `$price` that i want to change depending on what the `$type` variable is. For some reason in the email that gets sent, there is nothing. I have set `$price` to some random text outside of the if and then i works, so i know it isn't the mail function. Anybody know why this if statement doesn't work?

***PHP***

```
$type = "type 2";

if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "249 kr";
if( $type == "type2" ) $price = "349 kr";


$headers = 'From: xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject!';
$message = $price; 

mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Thanks

Btw, before people get mad, i have been searching and followed a few things but nothing has worked.

***edit***
the correct way to do it is:

```
$type = "type 2";

    if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "249 kr";
    else                   $price = "349 kr";


    $headers = 'From: xxxxxx@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject!';
    $message = $price; 

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Thanks Maja

Comment: Where is `$type` set in your code? Are you sure there aren't any spaces in the string? Have you tried dumping the variables to see what you have?

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump($type)` to see what you're dealing with?

Comment: "i have been searching and followed a few things but nothing has worked." Be more specific. What are these "things" you have followed?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. j08691: $type is set a bit farther up in the code. Gabirel: Sorry, i meant that i had searched to  try to find out why it wasn't working but could't find the answer. Got the answer now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$type` can only be "type1" or "type2", you should write it this way:

```
if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "249 kr";
else                   $price = "349 kr";
```

If the price now appears as "349 kr", you might have a wrong value in `$type`.

You should also consider

```
 if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "249 kr"; else
 if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "349 kr";
 else                   $price = "error";
```

Comment: Please DO NOT write code in that style (horizontal) and always put the `{ }` that will ensure you never miss anything outside the IF it should be.

Comment: In your second example, shouldn't `$type == "type1"` be `$type == "type2"`?

Comment: You should consider calling: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Given your post, the only thing I can imagine is that `$type` doesn't have `"type1"` or `"type2"`, so `$price` is never assigned, because the IF statements aren't true.

You can do

```
if( $type === 'type1' ) {
  $price = 'something';
}
else {
  $price = 'something default';
}
```

So at least it will always have something assigned.

Also, you can check what comes inside `$type` doing `var_dump($type)`

Answer (score 0):

you should check $type isset or not:

```
$price='';
if( isset($type) ){
 if( $type == "type1" ) $price = "249 kr";
 if( $type == "type2" ) $price = "349 kr";
}
```